# Showing PL/SQL ERROR : ORA-00947: not enough values

Tags: plsql, ora-00947

Please help me, how to fill in the correct values?
Because the value is always less, and showing ERR not enough values [the error is in here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSqK0.png)

Here is my code :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER REGION_HILMI_TRIGGER_WARNING
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON REGION_HILMI
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
warning VARCHAR2(400);
BEGIN 
IF INSERTING THEN 
warning:='Terjadi penambahan data di tabel regions, dengan
nilai region_id='||:NEW.region_id||' dan 
region_name='||:NEW.region_name; 
ELSIF UPDATING THEN 
warning:='Terjadi perubahan data di tabel regions, dengan 
nilai lama region_id='||:OLD.region_id||', 
region_name='||:OLD.region_name||' nilai baru 
region_id='||:NEW.region_id||', region_name='||:NEW.region_name;
ELSIF DELETING THEN 
warning:='Terjadi penghapusan data di tabel regions untuk 
region_id='||:OLD.region_id||' dan region_name='||:OLD.region_name; 
END IF; 
INSERT INTO REGION_HILMI_HISTORY(OLD_REGION_ID,OLD_REGION_NAME,NEW_REGION_ID,NEW_REGION_NAME,CHANGE_TIME,DESCRIPTION)
    VALUES(REGION_HILMI_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL,USER,TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),warning);
END; 
/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your INSERT statement shows only 4 items in the `VALUES` clause but 6 in the column name list. They must both match.

Answer (score 1):

> thankss sir, @TenG
> solved with adding this scripts :

```
INSERT INTO REGION_HILMI_HISTORY(OLD_REGION_ID,OLD_REGION_NAME,NEW_REGION_ID,NEW_REGION_NAME,CHANGE_TIME,DESCRIPTION)

    
VALUES(REGION_HILMI_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL,:OLD.REGION_NAME,:NEW.REGION_ID,:NEW.REGION_NAME,TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),warning);
```

Comment: Your correction following the answer provided by @TenG solves the error message, but if the names of the columns follow some logic, I don't think your second insert is correct in the sense of implementing a correct functionality. I mean, is there any logic in inserting a new value from a sequence in the field named OLD_REGION_ID? Wouldn't it be more logical to insert the value OLD.region_id?

Besides, what is the type of the column CHANGE_TIME? SYSDATE is a function returning a value of type DATE, so performing a TO_DATE over that value doesn't make sense, TO_DATE expects to get a VARCHAR2 as

Answer (score 0):

now then I tried to insert data into my primary table sir,

but it showing error like this appears, after i setting up the trigger

[click to show image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EByEG.png)

now it solved....
problem on trigger,

i change (TO_CHAR) >>> (TO_DATE)

error :

```
VALUES(REGION_HILMI_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL,:OLD.REGION_NAME,:NEW.REGION_ID,:NEW.REGION_NAME,TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),warning);
```

work :

```
VALUES(REGION_HILMI_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL,:OLD.REGION_NAME,:NEW.REGION_ID,:NEW.REGION_NAME,TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),warning);
```